# Using Redis for in-memory caching and DynamoDB (or Cassandra) for URL shortener

Tags: redis, nosql

I am a beginner programmer and am building a web service for a URL shortener, and am considering which NoSQL to use. I only need to store original urls and shortened ones, so Redis is an obvious choice as it is very fast. But Redis is limited to the memory size, whereas other key-value NoSQL like DynamoDB or Cassandra stores data in the disk. Do you think it makes sense to use Redis as a caching for heavy-read requests and use other NoSQL as a database at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible that you can use Redis for caching and use another NoSql tool for persistence. In fact, you should consider the complexity of your project such as the number of concurrent visitors, hardware you can afford etc. Redis can also store the data in disk so when you restart the server, your cached data will retain. However; it also stores all of them in memory which is the secret of Redis being so fast. You should also consider storing the data in Redis as binary rather than Json which will decrease the use of memory a lot. You can use encoding libraries such as Protobuf which will help you save huge amount of memory. If your project seems to get more complex in the near future, you can also use a RDMS as a database server for your future needs that will provide you distinct features.